# File isn't getting created in the phone's external storage

Tags: android, file, android-studio, android-external-storage

I have used this code for creating a file in my Phone's external storage. Please note that I've set the permissions for Read and Write in my Manifest file.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Date now = new Date();
String fileName = formatter.format(now) + ".txt"; //like 20170602.txt

File directory = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File file = new File(directory, fileName);

String bodyOfFile = "Body of file!";
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fos.write(bodyOfFile.getBytes());
    fos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My `LogCat` is showing the below. I can't see the file  `20170602.txt` in that particular location. In my `Download` folder, there isn't any file with that name. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong.

```
D/tag: Directory: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.pc.tab/files/Download
D/tag: File: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.pc.tab/files/Download/20170605.txt
```

**UPDATE**:

I'm using MOTO G4 for running this app. I found the `20170602.txt` file on Internal Storage.

```
File Manager --> `LOCAL` tab ( Upper right ) --> Internal Storage --> Android --> data --> com.pc.tab --> files --> Download --> 20170602.txt
```

Comment: are there any logs from e.printStackTrace() ?

Comment: Questions-- Did you [request/secure the permission if API > 22](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)?   (may not be necessary for download directory.. not sure offhand)  Also, are you getting any error caught by the catch?

Comment: No error logs from printStackTrace. @A.Edwar

Comment: your code should work, anyway try file.createNewFile() and check the returned value 
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#createNewFile()

Comment: Not sure but maybe you are looking at the wrong folder. You can install ES File Explorer https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en and locate the exact file path given.

Comment: Did you get my answer? or the problem was something else? I'm interested.

Comment: maybe your file is created but you are checking in different folder check this path /storage/emulated/0/Download

Comment: I used to see `ExternalStorage ` every time as getExternalFilesDir is for SD Card's Internal Storage. But in my phone, It was created in Internal Storage as mentioned in my updated question. How far it is true? or am I assuming `Internal storage` wrong ? @ArpitPatel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to separate the directory and the file itself

```
File directory = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File file = new File(directory, fileName);
```

In your code you call mkdirs on the file you are want to write on, its an error because mkdirs makes your file be an a directory. You should call mkdirs for the directory only so its will be created if its not exist, and the file will be created automatically when you create new FileOutputStream object for this file.

Your code should look like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Date now = new Date();
String fileName = formatter.format(now) + ".txt"; //like 20170602.txt

File directory = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File file = new File(directory, fileName);

String bodyOfFile = "Body of file!";
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fos.write(bodyOfFile.getBytes());
    fos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Got it. Please see my updated question. 
I used to see `ExternalStorage` every time as getExternalFilesDir is for SD Card's Internal Storage. But in my phone, It was created in Internal Storage as mentioned in my updated question. How far it is true? or am I assuming Internal storage wrong ?